# How to group an array of objects by key in this case

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a way to group an array of objects by an object key then create a new array of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of menu objects:

```
let menus = [
    {id: 1, parentId: 0, text: 'Home'},
    {id: 2, parentId: 0, text: 'About'},
    {id: 3, parentId: 0, text: 'Product'},
    {id: 4, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 1'},
    {id: 5, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 2'},
    {id: 6, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 3'},
    {id: 7, parentId: 0, text: 'Contact'},
    {id: 8, parentId: 7, text: 'Contact child 1'},
    {id: 9, parentId: 0, text: 'Blog'},
]
```

I want to make a new array of menu objects that's grouped by `parentId`

```
[
    {id: 1, parentId: 0, text: 'Home'},
    {id: 2, parentId: 0, text: 'About'},
    {id: 3, parentId: 0, text: 'Product', child: [
        {id: 4, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 1'},
        {id: 5, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 2'},
        {id: 6, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 3'},
    ]},
    {id: 7, parentId: 0, text: 'Contact', child: [
        {id: 8, parentId: 7, text: 'Contact child 1'},
    ]},
    {id: 9, parentId: 0, text: 'Blog'},
]
```

**UPDATE**
this is my code:

```
let newListMenu = []
menus.forEach(it => {
   let childrenData = []
   if (it.parentId&& it.parentId!== 0) {
       let parent = menus.find(_it => _it.Id == it.parentId)
       childrenData.push(it)
       parent.child= child
    } else {
       newListMenu.push(it)
    }
 })
```

Comment: is it for wordpress ? i

Comment: If you are comfortable using a library then I would suggest lodash you can do something like `_.groupBy(data, 'parentId')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Array.reduce` easily.

Here I have demonstrated a case where you have multi level of nesting. That is you can have child nodes inside a child node. If you have only one level of nesting you can use the commented loginc in the code for finding the parent node.

See code comments for implementation details.

```js
const menus = [{ id: 1, parentId: 0, text: 'Home' }, { id: 2, parentId: 0, text: 'About' }, { id: 3, parentId: 0, text: 'Product' }, { id: 4, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 1' }, { id: 5, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 2' }, { id: 6, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 3' }, { id: 7, parentId: 0, text: 'Contact' }, { id: 8, parentId: 7, text: 'Contact child 1' }, { id: 9, parentId: 0, text: 'Blog' }, { id: 10, parentId: 6, text: 'New Node' }];

const findParentNode = (nodes, child) => {
  let parent;
  // Loop through input array
  // Check if the id of any node is matching with the parent id 
  nodes.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.id === child.parentId) {
      parent = item;
      return; // Break loop
    } else if(item.child && item.child.length) {
      // Check the child nodes
      const newParent = findParentNode(item.child, child);
      parent = newParent ? newParent : parent;
      return; // Break loop
    }
  });
  return parent;
}
const groupedMenu = menus.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // Use this if you have one level of nesting.
  // const parentNode = acc.find(node => node.id === curr.parentId);
  
  // Find the parent node from the accumulator list and the current node
  const parentNode = findParentNode(acc, curr);
  
  // If parent node is found, push the current node to the child node of parent
  // Else push the node to accumulator
  if (parentNode) {
    parentNode.child ? parentNode.child.push(curr) : parentNode.child = [curr] 
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(groupedMenu);
```

Comment: Please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for

Comment: this is the most appropriate answer i upvoted this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const menus = [
  {id: 1, parentId: 0, text: 'Home'},
  {id: 2, parentId: 0, text: 'About'},
  {id: 3, parentId: 0, text: 'Product'},
  {id: 4, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 1'},
  {id: 5, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 2'},
  {id: 6, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 3'},
  {id: 7, parentId: 0, text: 'Contact'},
  {id: 8, parentId: 7, text: 'Contact child 1'},
  {id: 9, parentId: 0, text: 'Blog'},
];
const nested = menus.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // if parentId is 0, add to acc.
  if (item.parentId === 0) {
    return [
      ...acc,
      item,
    ];
  }

  // else find the parent.
  const parentIndex = acc.findIndex(parent => parent.id === item.parentId);
  const parent = acc[parentIndex];
  const children = parent.children ?? [];

  // update the array item at index.
  return Object.assign(
    [],
    acc,
    {
      [parentIndex]: {
        ...parent,
        children: [...children, item], // add the item as a child.
      },
    },
  );
}, []);

console.log(nested);
```

EDIT: This will only add the children on a single level. For multiple levels of nesting, you should probably do recursion.

Comment: this code will only group 1 layer nested you should mention that

Answer (score 0):

```js
let menus = [
    {id: 1, parentId: 0, text: 'Home'},
    {id: 2, parentId: 0, text: 'About'},
    {id: 3, parentId: 0, text: 'Product'},
    {id: 4, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 1'},
    {id: 5, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 2'},
    {id: 6, parentId: 3, text: 'Product Category 3'},
    {id: 7, parentId: 0, text: 'Contact'},
    {id: 8, parentId: 7, text: 'Contact child 1'},
    {id: 9, parentId: 0, text: 'Blog'},
]

function getUniqGroupList(data, val) {
    var grouped = [];
    data.forEach(function (a) {
      if (!this[a[val]]) {
        this[a[val]] = {
          parentId: a[val],
          items: []
        };
        grouped.push(this[a[val]]);
      }
      this[a[val]].items.push(a);
    }, Object.create(null));

    return grouped;
}
  
var d = getUniqGroupList(menus,'parentId');
console.log(d);
```